# jQuery password strength meter that uses images

Tags: jquery, passwords

I'm looking for a password strength meter that uses images to illustrate the strength of the password.

I've seen a lot that uses text, but I couldn't find a way to properly change the text to a desired image I wanted.

Is there any simple implementation I can use that can answer my needs?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean like a penny-arcade strength test machine where a man with bigger muscles means a stronger password? (odd analogy, but same concept)?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried? Just use an `<img>` tag and change the src attribute. Or better, use a background image divided in several regions and change the visible region via CSS.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I've tried using this http://n0nick.net/jquery/password-strength/ example and replacing the text bits on the .js file to img tags, but it just echo's the tags without displaying the images.

Comment: You'd also have to change `container.text()` to `container.html()`. That said, it would be better to add an image tag once and change the `src` attribute of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any password strength plugins giving this option from the box. Just take the plugin you picked and change the code parts that shows the messages and put `<img />` instead. If you are having a problem with that tell me the plugin you chose and I'll help you with that.

**CODE:**

```
container.text(settings.texts[level]).attr('class', 'password_strength ' + _class);
```

Change .text to .html and remember to add the images like thus:

```
        'texts' : {
        1 : "<img src='....' />",
        2 : "<img src='....' />",
        3 : "<img src='....' />",
        4 : "<img src='....' />",
        5 : "<img src='....' />"
    }
```

And everything should be sorted.

Comment: I've tried using this n0nick.net/jquery/password-strength example and replacing the text bits on the .js file to img tags, but it just echo's the tags without displaying the images.

Comment: that's because the plugin uses jquery's text() function and not html() so you can't add html, change this.